# How to handle columns not existing in SQL select statements?

Tags: sql

I am dealing with a single Table T1 with a variable scheme.
Concrete, there is a maximum of columns a, b, c, d, e - however: at the moment a request is made, the table may only contain a subset of these columns (e.g. a, b, e).

I need to create a table that always shows all columns.

However, if I "

```
Select 
a AS newNameA, 
b AS newNameB, 
c AS newNameC, 
d AS newNameD, 
e AS newNameE
FROM T1
```

I am getting an errors when column e is not available in the source table (column not found). Unfortunately I need to do the renaming as the actual column names are extremely unnice.

Is there something elegant (or unelegant) that would work and provide me

```
Select 
IFEXISTS(a AS newNameA), 
IFEXISTS(b AS newNameB), 
IFEXISTS(c AS newNameC), 
IFEXISTS(d AS newNameD), 
IFEXISTS(e AS newNameE)
FROM T1
```

(unfortunately this does not not work, but I hope it tells what I am looking for)
Thank you so much in advance,
Urs

Comment: `select * from table`, and then manage the number of columns returned. Or dynamic SQL.

Comment: How can your table have variable schema?

Comment: This sounda like a highly-suspect implementation! Almost certainly what is going on is a bad idea and will require you to dynamically build and execute your sql. Please tag your database.

Comment: If you have a variable schema, it is probably better to use a NoSQL database instead of a RDBMS.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Does the table have a primary key?

Answer (score 0):

This might require some TLC depending on your particular RDBMS platform but should get you started

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)='select '

select @sql += column_name + ','
from information_schema.columns
where table_schema='dbo' and table_name='T1'

set @sql=Replace(@sql + ' from T1', ', from',' from')

execute (@sql)
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this as well. this offers quite some interesting opportunities for doing things afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Postgres, you could convert the row to JSON:

```
select row_data ->> 'a' as newnamea,
       row_data ->> 'b' as newnameb,
       row_data ->> 'c' as newnamec, 
       ....
from (
   select to_jsonb(t1) as row_data
   from t1
) tj
```

You probably want to cast the expressions to the correct data type in the outer select (as converting the row to JSON and back loses the data type information)

Most modern DBMS have some kind of function to convert the entire row into a JSON value.

Comment: Thank you, this looks like an very elegant solution. I didnt think of this. This may work. Thank you.